# What would cause the same call to be done multiple times in a row?

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony-1.4

I've run across another intermittent problem in Symfony 1.4. Sometimes an action is repeated multiple times usually with something like a file upload. This ends up with the file "uploaded" more than once.

I am using Zend Framework with Symfony 1.4.

How would the same action be called more than once when the user hasn't called the action more than once?

**Edit:**

The file upload is straight `HTTP POST`, no AJAX. The file is loaded via a multi-part encoding and is processed on the server and then uploaded to S3 bucket for storage using the Zend Amazon S3 component.

It isn't double click of the submit button as I was testing trying to track down the problem and was able to see it occur on my dev machine. We also disable the button once click to stop accidental double clicks.

Only a few of the files from the Zend Framework are included that provide specific functionality needed such as interacting with S3 and OAuth. This is the [suggested approach](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/17?orm=Doctrine) by Sensiolabs for extending Symfony 1.4 functionality.

I do use the Zend Autoloader and I'm now wondering if I need to approach that slightly differently?

Comment: Show some code... are you redirecting? How are you uploading a file? chunked? Ajax? there's very little to go on here... also: you're using symfony1.4, why tag using the Symfony2 tag?

Comment: Using Zend Framework AND Symfony Framework is a very unlikely situation. Aren't you talking about Zend Engine, or Zend Studio ? Zend Guard later ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not something as simple as a user double clicking a submit button?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I've added detail to the original question. Sorry about the Symfony 2 it was only meant to be the Symfony 1.4 and straight symfony tag. The Symfony 2 one was added by accident.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I've added additional detail about using Zend & Symfony together. It is the suggested approach for extending Symfony functionality.

Comment: @TimFountain the button is disabled on the first click to stop accidental double clicks.